# an equation in a component of identity in a lie group

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

could any one help me how to solve :

prove that there exist solution for the equation $x^2=y$ in identity component of a lie group. I dont know how to start this one, what is the specia; about  component of identity?
well  for $y=e$ we get $x=e$

Comment: It is not clear where this question comes from, can you give more context? One could imagine trying to trace solutions by moving $y$ around, starting at $y=e$ (where by the way there are in general _more_ solutions than just $x=e$), which is an approach that would require a connected group. But it is not at all clear that this is actually a very promising angle of attack.

Comment: component of identity is an Normal Subgroup of the Lie Group, so can we just try to see in a group this kind of equation has solution or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false: the matrix
$$
  y=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}
$$
lies in the identity component of $G=\mathbf{GL}(2,\mathbf R)$ (which is the subset of matrices with positive determinant), but the equation $x^2=y$ for $x\in G$ has no solution, as can be checked by writing the equations for the matrix coefficients explicitly and showing the absence of real solutions.

See also [this question relating this equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191228/image-of-matrix-exponential-map) to the image of the exponential map, and [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200743/non-surjectivity-of-the-exponential-map-to-gl2-r).